# Closed subset of a metrizable space has compact boundary iff is of countable character

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, solution-verification

I want to prove that a closed subset $A$ of a metrizable space $X$ has compact boundary iff is of countable character i.e. there exists neighbourhoods $U_n$ of $A$ such that for every neighbourhood $V \supset A$, there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $U_n \subset V$. Let's call the neighbourhoods satisfying the condition a local base at $A$.

$\implies$ part. For every neighbourhood $V \supset A$, it is also a neighbourhood of $\partial A$. Thus there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $B(\partial A, 1/n) \subset V$. Thus $B(\partial A, 1/n) \cup \operatorname{int}(A)$ suffices.

$\impliedby$ part. Assume that $\partial A$ is not compact. Since it is metrizable, it is not countably compact, thus it has a closed discrete countably infinite subset $\{x_1, x_2, \ldots\}$. Let $U_n$ be a countable local base at $A$. By normality of $X$, there exists discrete family of open sets $V_n$ satisfying $x_n \in V_n \subset U_n$. Since $x_n \in \partial A$, we can pick $y_n \in V_n \setminus A$. Then $Y = \{y_n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is a discrete family of points thus closed, and $X \setminus Y$ is a neighbourhood of $A$ which doesn't contain any $U_n$, which is a contradiction.

Is this right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I agree with your proof, as an outline. It'll depend on what you can assume known whether it's a complete proof or not. E.g. why is your $Y$ discrete, it might need an argument to convince a critical teacher. The existence of the $V_n$ also assumes more knowledge about normality beyond the definition? I'm not saying it's invalid, just that it could be expanded to fill in all the details for the various claims that are made.

Comment: I thought $Y$ is discrete because for every $x \in X$, there exists a neighbourhood of $x$ intersecting at most one $V_n$ and, a fortiori, one $y_n \in V_n$. I got the $V_n$s by applying Tietze extension theorem on $x_n \mapsto n$.